# Access YouTube with ASP.NET and YoutubeFisher but gets HTTP Error 403

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-headers, json.net

I'm trying to use [YoutubeFisher](http://youtubefisher.codeplex.com/) library with ASP.NET. I make an HttpWebRequest to grab html content, process  the contest to extract the video links and display links on the web page. I managed to make it work on localhost. I can retrieve video links and download the video on the locahost. But when I push it to the Server, it works only if I send the request from the same Server. If that page is accessed by a client browser, the client can see the links properly, but when link is clicked the client gets the HTTP Error 403, everytime the client clicks on the link even though the link is correct.

My analysis is that when the Server makes HttpWebRequest to grab HTML contet, it sends HTTP header as well. The HTML content (links to the video file) that is sent back from YouTube server, I think, will reponse to only the request that matches that HTTP header, that is sent from the Server. So, when client clicks on the link it sends request to YouTube server with different HTTP header.

So, I'm thinking of getting the HTTP header from the client, then modify the Server HTTP header to include HTTP header info of the client before making HttpWebRequest. I'm not quite sure if this will work. As far as I know, HTTP heaer cannot be modified.

Below is the code that makes HttpWebRequest from YouTubeFisher library,

```
public static YouTubeService Create(string youTubeVideoUrl)
        {
            YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService();
            service.videoUrl = youTubeVideoUrl;

            service.GetVideoPageHtmlSource();
            service.GetVideoTitle();
            service.GetDownloadUrl();

            return service;
        }

        private void GetVideoPageHtmlSource()
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(videoUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            videoPageHtmlSource = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            resp.Close();
        }
```

> Client browses the page but the links are there but give HTTP 403:

[image]

[image]

> Browse the page the from the Server itself, everything works as expected:

[image]

How do I make HttpWebRequest on the behalf of the client then? Is my analysis of this problem correct?

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Use an http monitor such as Charles, Fiddler or even Firebug to find out what additional headers are being sent from the brower in the success case. I suspect you'll need to duplicate one or more of `accept`, `user-agent` or `referer`.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've just assumed that youtube has those links encoded so that they only work for the original request IP.  If that were the case it would be far more difficult.  I have no clue if this is the case or not, try forwarding all the header elements you can before going down this route...

The only possibility that comes to mind is that you'd have to use a javascript request to download the page to the client's browser, then upload that to your server for processing, or do the processing in javascript.

Or you could have the client download the video stream via your server, so your server would pass through the data.  This would obviously use a ton of your bandwidth.